# How to best organize an SVN repository for multiple versions of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, svn

Have a group of related projects running in SQL Server 2005 for which I have organized an SVN repository like so:

• \
• \Scripts
• \SSAS
    ○ \Project1_OLAP
    ○ \Project2_OLAP
    ○ ...
• \SSIS
    ○ \ETL_Source1
    ○ \ETL_Source2
    ○ ...
• \SSRS
    ○ \Project1_Canned
    ○ \Project1_AdHoc
    ○ ...

In the very near future, my organization will begin a full-scale conversion and migration, project by project, to a SQL Server 2008R2 server.   There will be a period of time where both the 2005 and 2008 version of the same project will need to be supported and running.  There are some unknowns in the new environment, so I would need to be prepared on the worst case for a number of months of parallel support.  Eventually, though the 2008R2 code would become the 'trunk'.  How would you recommend to incorporate the 2008R2 version of the projects in that folder structure?

My team are beginners at SVN and version control systems in general, so a priority would be simplicity, and making it very clear which version they are working on during this transition period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SVN branch, using the same structure and base code as your trunk.  This allows for the same directory scheme, and everything.  When you are done with the final conversion, you merge all the code from that branch into Trunk, making Trunk have all the code in question.

Comment: Good stuff!  For the first time I see the wisdom of the trunk and branches layout of an SVN repository.